# Make stream accessible to multiple machines

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, opencv, flask, camera

I have a small USB camera connected to my Raspberry Pi 3b+. I would like to stream whatever that camera is looking at over the internet (or in this case, local network) to any other machine that visits certain address.

When it comes to software setup, the Raspberry Pi is hosting a simple Flask server (whose code you can find below) that's supposed to show the stream on its own page.

On my PC, I host another simple React server that just uses `<iframe>` tag to stream that video from Flask server on its webpage.

Once more: camera looks at something -> that's streamed on Flask server -> that's captured and streamed on React frontend.

The implementation seems to serve its purpose until two or more people (from different machines) want to look at the camera's stream (React.js frontend).
It's only available for the first person who looks at it.

One thing I would point out is the fact that I can't access camera globally, so I need to (for some reason) access it down there in the function.

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, request, redirect
import cv2
import sys
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

def gen_frames():  # generate frame by frame from camera
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        success, frame = camera.read()  # read the camera frame
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@app.route('/move', methods=['POST'])
def move():
    print(request.form.get('direction'))
    return redirect("/")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video streaming home page."""
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="192.168.1.4",port="1234",debug=True)
```

`index.html`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8  offset-lg-2">
                    <h3 class="mt-5">Live Streaming</h3>
                    <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" width="100%">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

React frontend:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
// import axios from 'axios';

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {stream: true};
  }

  loadStream = () => {
    if(this.state.stream) {
      return <>
      <img width="500px" height="500px"
        src="http://192.168.1.4:1111/video_feed">
      </img>
      <br/>
    </>
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <>
      {this.loadStream()}  
    </>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is when the first client request video_feed the main process stays blocked then the second client request video_feed and the server throws a timeout therefore the server killed the process, create a new one and assign to the second client. I recently worked in a raspberry video streaming project using opencv and the official raspberry pi camera.

You should take a look at [Miguel Grinberg's blog](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask/page/8) he implements threads in a fashionable way, basically managing its events and logic in [base_camera class](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-video-streaming/blob/master/base_camera.py). You can implemented using opencv as follows:

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, request, redirect
from flask_cors import CORS
from camera_opencv import Camera

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

def gen(camera):
    """Video streaming generator function."""
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen(Camera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@app.route('/move', methods=['POST'])
def move():
    print(request.form.get('direction'))
    return redirect("/")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video streaming home page."""
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="192.168.1.4",port="1234",debug=True)
```

`camera_opencv.py`

```
import os
import cv2
from base_camera import BaseCamera


class Camera(BaseCamera):
    video_source = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super(Camera, self).__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def set_video_source(source):
        Camera.video_source = source

    @staticmethod
    def frames():
        camera = cv2.VideoCapture(Camera.video_source)
        if not camera.isOpened():
            raise RuntimeError('Could not start camera.')

        while True:
            # read current frame
            _, img = camera.read()

            # encode as a jpeg image and return it
            yield cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tobytes()
```

`base_camera.py`

```
import time
import threading
try:
    from greenlet import getcurrent as get_ident
except ImportError:
    try:
        from thread import get_ident
    except ImportError:
        from _thread import get_ident


class CameraEvent(object):
    """An Event-like class that signals all active clients when a new frame is
    available.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.events = {}

    def wait(self):
        """Invoked from each client's thread to wait for the next frame."""
        ident = get_ident()
        if ident not in self.events:
            # this is a new client
            # add an entry for it in the self.events dict
            # each entry has two elements, a threading.Event() and a timestamp
            self.events[ident] = [threading.Event(), time.time()]
        return self.events[ident][0].wait()

    def set(self):
        """Invoked by the camera thread when a new frame is available."""
        now = time.time()
        remove = None
        for ident, event in self.events.items():
            if not event[0].isSet():
                # if this client's event is not set, then set it
                # also update the last set timestamp to now
                event[0].set()
                event[1] = now
            else:
                # if the client's event is already set, it means the client
                # did not process a previous frame
                # if the event stays set for more than 5 seconds, then assume
                # the client is gone and remove it
                if now - event[1] > 5:
                    remove = ident
        if remove:
            del self.events[remove]

    def clear(self):
        """Invoked from each client's thread after a frame was processed."""
        self.events[get_ident()][0].clear()


class BaseCamera(object):
    thread = None  # background thread that reads frames from camera
    frame = None  # current frame is stored here by background thread
    last_access = 0  # time of last client access to the camera
    event = CameraEvent()

    def __init__(self):
        """Start the background camera thread if it isn't running yet."""
        if BaseCamera.thread is None:
            BaseCamera.last_access = time.time()

            # start background frame thread
            BaseCamera.thread = threading.Thread(target=self._thread)
            BaseCamera.thread.start()

            # wait until frames are available
            while self.get_frame() is None:
                time.sleep(0)

    def get_frame(self):
        """Return the current camera frame."""
        BaseCamera.last_access = time.time()

        # wait for a signal from the camera thread
        BaseCamera.event.wait()
        BaseCamera.event.clear()

        return BaseCamera.frame

    @staticmethod
    def frames():
        """"Generator that returns frames from the camera."""
        raise RuntimeError('Must be implemented by subclasses.')

    @classmethod
    def _thread(cls):
        """Camera background thread."""
        print('Starting camera thread.')
        frames_iterator = cls.frames()
        for frame in frames_iterator:
            BaseCamera.frame = frame
            BaseCamera.event.set()  # send signal to clients
            time.sleep(0)

            # if there hasn't been any clients asking for frames in
            # the last 10 seconds then stop the thread
            if time.time() - BaseCamera.last_access > 10:
                frames_iterator.close()
                print('Stopping camera thread due to inactivity.')
                break
        BaseCamera.thread = None
```

`wsgi.py`

```
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

`Gunicorn's script:`

```
gunicorn --worker-class gevent --bind 0.0.0.0:1234 wsgi:app
```

I would recommend you to use gunicorn's worker as per coroutines request because is good for I/O bounded applications(for example stream using opencv) for that you must install asynchronous libraries as [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) or [evenlet](https://eventlet.net/). If you you like to take a look to the different worker types of [medium](https://medium.com/@nhudinhtuan/gunicorn-worker-types-practice-advice-for-better-performance-7a299bb8f929) has a good intro.

Good luck, regards.